# Why is my app UI not updating even when I use dispatch_async to jump out of the background queue?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, dispatch-async

I have a function for checking the uniqueness of a phone number in a signup view controller. However when I jump to the main queue to update a UITextField.rightView with a button, nothing happens. The same update occurs when the phone number is too short or too long without any problems. For some reason when I try and do it this way I get no changes

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if !unique {
                self.verificationField.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
                self.shouldShowVerificationFieldError(true)
                self.uniquenessAlert.hidden = true
            }
            self.activity.stopAnimating()
        })

func shouldShowVerificationFieldError(shouldShow: Bool) {
    if shouldShow {
        verificationField.rightView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(self.verificationField.frame.maxX - 30,0,25,25))
        verificationField.rightView?.addSubview(verificationError)
    }
    else {
        verificationField.rightView = nil
    }
}
```

The activity indicator stops animating as I would expect.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    //checkValidContact()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0.0
    })
    switch textField.tag {
    case 0:
        break
    case 1:
        if validateVerification(textField.text ?? "") || textField.text == ""{
            shouldShowVerificationFieldError(false)
        }
        else {
            verificationField.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            shouldShowVerificationFieldError(true)
            uniquenessAlert.hidden = true
        }
    case 2:
        if validatePassword(textField.text ?? "") || textField.text == ""{
            shouldShowPasswordFieldError(false)
        }
        else {
            passwordField.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            shouldShowPasswordFieldError(true)
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this `verificationField`? What type is it? Is it visible? What does the setter for `rightView` do?

Comment: it's a `UITextField` it is always visible. The setter simply creates the rightView of verificationField and adds a button to that subview.

Comment: Probably something wrong with your view, not the `dispatch`